# How I know when the last time URL was requested?

Tags: node-red

I need to know the last time when a specific page was requested.

For example, in my flow, I create a simple webservices1 that returns a JSON object (random number), and at the same time, create another webservices2 that provides me the last request for my webservices1 and what number the person who requested my services1 obtained.

Comment: Why don't you just log the request and response in webservices1. Then use webservice2 to query the log

Comment: Please review the Coursera material from which this question is one of the assignments. You can use local context to store state between calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a local variable that refresh when the other webservices are requested, I thought also exist another node thar provide information about webServices but the solution was very simple , only create a global variable.